# Is there a method in ActiveRecord to remove a belongs_to association?

Tags: inheritance, activerecord, associations, shortcut

I have a Sinatra app that tags members of a service using a Sidekiq job. Here's one of the models.

```
class TagInstruction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag_job
end
```

I want to extend this system so it can tag members of a completely different service, using a different model. *Some* of the structure is the same, so I'm extending the class, but the actual tag information is set up differently, so there's a completely separate table underneath.

```
class LcTagInstruction < TagInstruction
  self.table_name = 'lc_tag_instructions'
  belongs_to :lc_tag_job
end
```

(NB. While `LcTagInstruction` uses *multiple* table inheritance, `LcTagJob` is similar enough to `TagJob` that I've used *single* table inheritance at that level.)

In an ideal world, of course, I'd be extending the class twice - once for the old service and once for the new - but this has proven to be too disruptive and take too much time and effort, so I'm putting in a dirty dirty hack and undefining some of the parent class's methods.

However, while I can `undef` individual methods, I'd like to be able to `undef` the `belongs_to` association as well. Is there something that can do this?

```
does_not_belong_to :tag_job
```

It should do something like this:

```
undef tag_job
undef tag_job=
undef build_tag_job
undef create_tag_job
undef create_tag_job!
```

Comment: Perhaps you could define the belongs_to using a polymorphic association as seen here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association